# How to get any map service without labels that´s not google

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I have a project in which I need the map without the names of the streets and without labels of some (or none) of the neighborhoods, areas, etc. How to get this OSM presentation in Openlayers 4? PS: I accessed Snazzy and got a mapless map setup easily, but from what I saw, the code is for the Google API, only, is that it? I want the OSM. Thankful.

Comment: You need an OSM tile server with a stylesheet without labels. This has already been answered several times. Use your favorite search engine. Also this question is offtopic for StackOverflow. http://gis.stackexchange.com and http://help.openstreetmap.org/ would be the correct place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia Labs runs a tile server with no labels: http://tiles.wmflabs.org/osm/slippymap2.html (check "OSM no-labels" from the layer list).

Make sure to check their terms of use.